# The output of the code snippet is not what i expected

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand why this code snippet using an altered version of the visitor patters is always printing the log V instead of A. Compiled using c++11 version.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A;
class B;
class Visitable;

class Visitor
{
    public:
    void visit(const A& a)
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void visit(const Visitable& v)
    {
        std::cout << "V" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void visit(const B& b)
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Visitable
{
    public:
        virtual void Accept(Visitor* visitor)
        {
            visitor->visit(*this);
        }
};

class A : public Visitable
{
};

class B : public Visitable
{
};

int main()
{
    Visitor* v = new Visitor();
    A* a = new A();
    
    a->Accept(v); // IT PRINTS V INSTEAD OF A.

    return 0;
}
```

I executed the code snipped, i was expecting to see the log A in the output console.

Comment: Because `*this` is `Visitable`?

Comment: First of all, inheritance is a one-way relationship. While `A` "is a" `Visitable`, the `Visitable` class is not an `A`. Second of all, virtual functions and polymorphism makes no sense unless you actually *override* the functions in the child classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `*this` is `Visitable` which matches the type of the parameter in the member function `void Visitor::visit(const Visitable&)` so that it is the only **viable** option and hence selected.

That is, the other two member function `void Visitor::visit(const A&)` and `void Visitor::visit(const B&)` are not viable since the passed argument in the call `visitor->visit(*this);` is of type `Visitable` while the parameter type in these member functions is `const A&` and `const B&` respectively.

---

> why is `this` a pointer to Visitable instead of `A`

Because as per the standard, inside the body of a non-const non-static member function `func` of a class `X`, the type of pointer `this` is `X*`. This means that `*this` is `X`. This can be seen(pun intended) from [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

> The expression this is a prvalue expression whose value is the **address of the implicit object parameter** (object on which the non-static member function is being called).

Comment: That's probably what i'm not understanding why is "this" a pointer to Visitable instead of A, so i should make the visitable pure virtual and implement the Accept in the concrete classes

Comment: @jsubi Because as per the standard, inside the body of a non-const non-static member function `func` of a class `X`, the type of pointer `this` is `X*`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 visitor->visit(*this);
```

This is a method of the `Visitable` class. Because of that, `this` is a pointer to a `Visitable`. The End.

This is true even if this instance of a class is a subclass. `this` is still a pointer to a `Visitable`, that's just how C++ works. That's the reason for the result of the overload resolution.